# ExtJS:: Grid's event after data show?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to scrollByDeltaY after data is loaded. What event I need to take? All events, I found, works before data is shown, and scroll doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe the grid's store "load" event and the do your scrollByDeltaY code.

```
myNiceGrid.getStore().on("load", myCcrollByDeltaYFunction);
```

Comment: I'm using loadData() method to that store, and in that case it doesn't firing "Load" event.

Comment: And when I override loadData() and added firing "load" to store, grid don't want to scroll down. Load event fired too early. Grid didn't render rows in that moment.

Comment: Edit your question and give us some code where you can see what else are you doing with the code to better help you!

Answer (score 2):

I use the refresh event of the gridview, works much better for me then the store load event:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    viewConfig: {
        listeners: {
            refresh: function(view) {}
        }
    }
});
```